# Visit only directories of a specific depth with Java 7

Tags: java, nio, directory-walk

When using the method

> java.nio.file.Files.walkFileTree(Path root, Set options, int maxDepth, FileVisitor visitor)

one can specify the *maximum* depth of files to visit. Is there also a way to specify that only paths of a specific, *exact* depth shall be visited?

More specifically, I only want to visit directories, but this could be easily checked with

```
if (attrs.isDirectory()) {
    // do something
}
```

in the `visitFile` callback.

---

Example: Assume I have a directory structure with the files `root/dir1/dir11/file.a` and `root/dir2/file.b` and I call `walkFileTree` on `root` with `maxDepth=2`. Then, I only want to process

```
root/dir1/dir11
```

I neither want to process the file `root/dir2/file.b`, which has also a depth of two, nor the other directory paths with a depth less than two:

```
root
root/dir1
root/dir2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interestingly, the naive implementation does exactly what I want:

```
Files.walkFileTree(root, EnumSet.noneOf(FileVisitOption.class), 2, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
    @Override
    public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path path, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
        if (attrs.isDirectory()) {
            process(path);
        }
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }
});
```

That is, for the given example, it will exactly only process `root/dir1/dir11`.

The solution makes use of the apparently contradictory approach to filter for *directories* in visit*Files*. However the JavaDoc of `walkFileTree` explains why this results in the desired behaviour:

> For each file encountered this method attempts to read its java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes. **If the file is not a directory** then the visitFile method is invoked with the file attributes.
>   (...)
>
> The maxDepth parameter is the maximum number of levels of directories to visit. (...) The visitFile method is invoked for all files, **including directories**, encountered at maxDepth (...)